# Cannot see JPEG files extracted from a .VOB video file by VLC on the Mac Finder or Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, video, vlc

I was hoping someone would be helpful with *"ghost"* files on an iMac.

With the **VLC media player app**. I was extracting JPEG files from a **.VOB video file** and saving them on my iMac.

When I looked for the files in the Mac SO X *Finder* and the *Terminal* (with UNIX commands) I could not see them.  I knew they were there, but were apparently invisible, or ghost files.

I tried saving the same file from within VLC, but it complained the file already existed and did I want to replace it?  So the file definitely existed. Again, I could not see the file in Finder nor Terminal.

As an experiment I used the Terminal to create a file of the same name.  There should have been an error message saying the file already existed, but there was no error and I could write the file as if it was new.  In theory, I should have overwritten the file I saved in VLC.

If the Finder or Terminal cannot see the JPEG files VLC extracted from the .VOB video file, then I'm back to square one.

Comment: My first guess is that VLC doesn't write them into the folder you think it should be writing them. Did you try to find them through Spotlight? Or by running `find ~ -name YOUR.JPG` in Terminal?

Comment: Also, I assume that you use Cmd-Opt-S to create snapshots. What is the target directory in Preferences->Video set to?